# Best jQuery drag and drop solution

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a rather complex project where there will be a lot of LI objects, I want to make them draggable and droppable into several predefined ULs and then execute specific commands depending which group of ULs it has been dropped into.

I've found a lot of different jQuery plugins for this, however I was wondering what would be the best and easiest to adapt to something like this?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JQuery UI component sortable. That component makes it possible to drag and drop Li elements between UL containers.

Comment: I though you can only use it to drag and drop within a UL? Thanks for the suggestion, time to check it out!

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius can be done with any element: http://aysites.com/ExplosionPills/demo (sortable on divs)